# Difference between vstest.console.exe and dotnet test commands

Tags: .net, unit-testing, vstest

Is there any difference between vstest.console.exe and dotnet test commands to run unit test from a terminal? Like when should you use one over the other. Is "vstest.console.exe" meant for only .Net framework and "dotnet test" for dotnet core projects? I can't find any specific answer that addresses this on google or in Microsoft's documentation.

The question in the below link comes close but the answer does not address the difference. I want to run my C# project in a build server with a script and was wondering which would be the best option to use.

[testing in .net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136887/testing-in-net-framework)

Comment: A few experiments can show that both work, and that's why no need to have documentation on "what is not supported".

Comment: Are you saying either could be used irrespective of the frameworks? Be it .net core or .net framework?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the **vstest.console.exe** used to run only **MSTests** at some point while **dotnet test** was designed to be more test framework agnostic and support other frameworks like **NUnit** and **xUnit** with potential to run them on different platforms (i.e. not only Windows as it was with **vstest.console.exe**).

According to the official documentation for [dotnet vstest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-vstest):

> The **dotnet-vstest** command runs the **VSTest.Console** command-line application to run automated unit tests.

MS also added an important note on that page recently stating that:

> The **dotnet vstest** command is superseded by **dotnet test**, which can now be used to run assemblies. See [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test).

So it seems like **dotnet test** is the way now :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest describes it.

Basically, using vstestconsole you need to use "**--testcasefilter**" instead of "--filter".

Comment: There is a difference between vstest and mstest - the former is a test runner and the later is a test framework. Both could be used independently.